# Use of logic:iterate with String array

Tags: java, arrays, struts, taglib

Im working with Struts and need to iterate  list of string array i-e

```
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

im using this code to iterate

```
<logic:iterate  name="myForm" id="syncStringArrayId" property="list">
            <tr>            
                <td><bean:write name="syncStringArrayId"  /></td>
                <td>2nd column should be index 1 of string array</td>
                <td>3rd column should be index 2 of string array</td>
            </tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

but when i execute this code it prints:

```
Column1                     Colmn2      Column3 
[Ljava.lang.String;@2803cc  Col2-Data   Col3-Data/value
```

means it is printing complete string array but im unable to print index of string array.

can any one please help me to find my mistake.

**EDIT**

Please advise if this is not possible at all as i can use some bean to achive the same thing like

```
List<someBean> list = new ArrayList<someBean>();
```

and data im going to save in String array i will save in the bean and that will work.

Comment: Use indexes to retrieve value from array.

Comment: @AleksandrM i tried using index as well but not getting exact idea, can you please explain a bit more.

Comment: So, your actual question is "I have a property of type String[] and I want to access one of its elements". If struts does not support just `syncStringArrayId[0]` (I do not know, it has been a long time since I used it), use EL (instead of `<bean:write..../>`, use `${syncStringArrayId[0]}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the lib solved my problem

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

i used the forEach loop to iterate the list like this.

```
<c:forEach items="${myForm.list}" var="bean">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${bean[0]}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${bean[2]}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${bean[1]}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Hope this will help someone, thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your List stores string array as object i.e List list = new ArrayList();so when you are iterating over the List it gives you String[] which will intern contain number of elements as it is an array and not single element and you will need to apply one more loop over it for printing the values from string[].
Hope you got what I meant to say .

Comment: no, no other loop is required, as i can get values of String[] using index[0], index[1] ...  etc that is not my issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, you have iterated over the `List`, but missed to iterate over the `String array`.

Could you please try:

```
<table>
    <logic:iterate  name="myForm" id="syncStringArrayId" property="list" indexId="indexId">
    <tr>
        <td><bean:write name="indexId" /></td>
        <logic:iterate name="syncStringArrayId" id="strValue"> 
            <td><bean:write name="strValue" /></td>
        </logic:iterate>          
    </tr>
    </logic:iterate> 
</table>
```